# PHP/WP 20-30s Image Upload

Tags: php, wordpress

I am uploading an image with the below code (github link below) and it takes about 20-30 seconds for a single 6MB photo to be uploaded. Does anyone have an idea why this might be?

https://github.com/hivepress/hivepress/blob/master/includes/controllers/class-attachment.php#L119

There is a demo of the Wordpress theme that I am using below, where you can see the exact same issue when you try to upload a photo. It takes a long time to load a photo.

https://rentalhive.hivepress.io/submit-listing/details/

I tried modifying the server side wordpress settings and also reduced the number of thumbnails that are being generated, but neither improved the upload speed...

Comment: I'd start by figuring out which part takes so long - the actual upload, or the subsequent processing. Take some `microtime` measurements inside the code at relevant points, and see what that tells you.

Comment: Thank you CBroe, any idea how I can test that without overwriting the plugin?

Comment: Why, you can always restore the original version later.